# Planning to buy new laptop "XPS 15 Touch" with windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, operating-systems

I am planning to buy 'HP - XPS 15 Touch' model laptop, I am windows 7 users and don't know much about windows 8 and i think it is right time to move to windows 8.1,  With window xp, 2000 & win 7 we used to buy Professional edition so that it can be hooked domain. Do we have version like home, professional & ultimate edition in windows 8 or something similar.... Does windows 8, 8.1 come in 32 bit version..

Is 32 bit version limited to 4BG of RAM like window 7, xp etc.. or it can support more than 8GB of RAM

Comment: There's *utterly* no reason to go 32 bit with modern windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 and 8.1 also come in 32 and 64Bit. The [32Bit version is still limited to 4GB of RAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_8). There are fewer editions. You have a basic/core Version and the Pro. There is also a Volume License Version called Enterprise for Business use. The 64Bit Core/Basis Edition is limited to 128GB of RAM and the Pro/Enterprise can use 512GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes magicandre1981 is correct. Just to add, if you want to compare the versions follow [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx) link.

For Windows 8.1 Pro and above there will be the functions of joining domains.
Also I'd advise you to choose 64bit, as you won't be limited by 4GB RAM and 64bit usually can 
use 64 bit AND 32bit programs, but not vice versa.